# How to solve $y'=\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2-y^2}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve ODE:

$$y'=\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2-y^2}$$

I do not know where to start! Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\textbf{I have converted to a community wiki answer, as a rather trivial manipulation does not warrant any rep.}$

$$
y' = \frac{\left(1+\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2\right)}{\left(1-\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2\right)}
$$
let $v = y/x$

yeilds
$$
xv' + v = \frac{\left(1+v^2\right)}{\left(1-v^2\right)}
$$
this is a separable.

Comment: Have you been able to solve it ?

Comment: @claudeleibovici  Yep I believe so (I did a fairly quick check) Shall I go the whole way? A useful sub was $v =\sqrt{t}$.

Comment: I am stuck with this ODE ! Just check that you have a solution. Thanks !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I was wrong in my rather rash comment..I made a mistake. As you have probably determined the solution is not a simple one..and $\sqrt{t}$ most certainly does not help.

Comment: I totally agree with you. To me, this looks as a monster ! Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

rewrite it in the form $$y'=\frac{1+\frac{y^2}{x^2}}{1-\frac{y^2}{x^2}}$$ and set $\frac{y}{x}=u$ with this ansatz we obtain
$$\frac{1-u^2}{u^3+u^2-u+1}du=\frac{dx}{x}$$

Comment: Have you been able to solve it ?

Comment: [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate+%281-x%5E2%29%2F%28x%5E3%2Bx%5E2-x%2B1%29) gets quite a mess for the left side

Comment: OK, but now ? What is the result of the integration of the lhs ?

Comment: @rossmillikan that's the output I got. So it looks like it's done the roots of the denominator .. It was that output that made me realise the error in my ways!

Comment: Yes, the way to do it by hand from here is a partial fraction decomposition.